# android app crashes at startup, Logcat: Didn't find class "[package name]" at /data/app/[package name]

Tags: android, web-services, crash, startup, logcat

hopefully you can help me with my problem. My application crashes at startup, so I tried to use LogCat to find the error. As mentioned in the title, the errormassage says:

```
07-29 03:49:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculate.firsttry/com.example.calculate.firsttry.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.calculate.firsttry.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.calculate.firsttry-1.apk
07-29 03:49:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.calculate.firsttry.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.calculate.firsttry-1.apk
```

So it seems like I missed some declaration somewhere. The problem is, I don't know where. This isn't my first app, and I thought I had repeated every step I did before.

This is the code of my App:

```
package com.example.calculate.firsttry;

 import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
 import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
 import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class AndroidWSDLFrontEnd extends Activity {

 private String METHOD_NAME = "add"; // our webservice method name
 private String NAMESPACE = "http://calculator.backend.org";;
 private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME; // NAMESPACE + method name
 private static final String URL = "http://10.35.108.154:8080/AndroidBackend/services/Calculator?wsdl";;// you must use ipaddress here, don’t use Hostname or localhost

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAddition);
 try
 {
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
 request.addProperty("a", 5);
 request.addProperty("b", 15);
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
 envelope.dotNet = true;
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
 Object result = envelope.getResponse();
 System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
 ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("Addition :" +result.toString());
 } catch (Exception E) {
 E.printStackTrace();
 ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.txtAddition)).setText("ERROR: "    + E.getClass().getName() + "," + E.getMessage());
 }
 }
 }
```

Maybe I missed something here. I can't specify the question anymore. All I got is the code and the error message. So how do I get my app to run?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some suggestions

1) declare activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file if not declared yet.

2) it seems you are trying to open `MainActivity` `class/Activity` and you added `AndroidWSDLFrontEnd` activity in the question, hope you are calling correct Activity, check names of respective classes in Manifest/ActivityDeclararion and at the time of starting Activity.

```
07-29 03:49:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.calculate.firsttry.**MainActivity**" // here it says MainActivity not found, Check the name of your activity
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the original problem, I forgot to change the name of the class in the manifest. Now it still doesn't work, there is an error in my code @ line 26, but since I tried to solve the posted error message, again thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

try by changing

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.calculate.firsttry.MainActivity"
        ............

    </activity>
```

to

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.calculate.firsttry.AndroidWSDLFrontEnd"
            ............

        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Android Studio 0.2.10 and had to perform a Gradle `clean` within Android Studio.